# Java Object method is not working

Tags: java

Good day!

I have two objects namely PLAYER AND GAME.. The player consists of variable `String playerName`. In the Player Object I have a method `public String getPlayer();` wherein a when you typed in a text in the text box, you can get the name.

I need to access the name in the GAME Object. But I cannot access it. My code is as follows:

PLAYER:

```
public class Player extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private String playerName;

    public Player(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, true);
        initComponents();
    }

    public Player() {
        this(null);
    }

    public String getPlayer() {
        playerName = txtPlayerName.getText();
        System.out.println(playerName);
        return playerName;
    }
```

}

GAME:

```
public class MainGame extends JDialog implements ActionListener {

    public MainGame(JDialog owner) {
        super(owner, true);
        initComponents();
        Player playerName = new Player();
        pName.setText(playerName.getPlayer());
        newGame();
    }
```

May I know what i am doing wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: is `txtPlayerName.getText()` in your `Player` class a typo? I don't see it anywhere else in your source.

Comment: @sarnold txtPlayerName is a JtextField and is Generated using Netbean's GUI

Comment: ah, thanks; you might not want to have a getter method on an object retrieve the value from a text field which may or may not exist in any specific view, and heaven forbid you may want to have two players in your game some day. :) I suggest initializing your player object with the player name retrieved from the GUI, and keep knowledge of the GUI out of your `Player` class, to the extent that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say:

"In the Player Object I have a method `public String getPlayerName();`"

while no such thing exists in your code. Perhaps you meant `public String getPlayer()`, since that method exists.

Also, take a look at your existing method:

```
public String getPlayer() {
    playerName = txtPlayerName.getText();
    System.out.println(playerName);
    return playerName;
}
```

Above it you have:

```
private String playerName;
```

In your `getPlayer()` method, you're accessing `txtPlayerName` which doesn't exist. You probably meant

```
this.playerName = playerName.getText();
```

although this won't solve your problem fully, since nowhere do I see a method that accesses the external `playerName` (`txtPlayerName` in your code).

Now that I've pointed out a few observations, I'm sure you can handle the rest.

Comment: the textPlayerName is a text field... if i input a text there, i would like to get the text...

Answer (score 1):

You using the default constructor, which does not initialize the components:

```
Player playerName = new Player();
```

This *could* be a problem.

Then, of course, `txtPlayerName` is not defined in the code snippet.

Finally - your confusing yourself and the other with variable and method names ;) Please rename the getter Method in `Player` to `getPlayerName()` (because you do return the players name) and the local variable `playerName` in the `MainGame` constructor to `player` (because now you create the `Player` dialog.

BTW - you don't show the `Player` dialog. Another chance for a solution to the problem. Call `playerName.setVisible(true)` and allow the user to enter a name.

---

*Responding to a comment*

`Player` has two constructors, the *default constructor* (no arguments) and another one (takes an instance of `JFrame`). The *other* constructor calls the magic method `initComponents()` and the default constructor dosn't. I don't know what has to be initialized, but this step is missing if you create a `Player` dialog with the default constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by using my default constructor and did not initialize the component? What should i do? THank you

Answer (score 0):

I think we should ask him what he meant by `I can not access it`.

What is the exception or compile error you are getting, and on what line.

Comment: There's no error.. I just cannot pass the playerName from the PLAYER OBJECT to the GAME OBJECT